# Error: “cannot call methods on masonry prior to initialization'” when combining masonry grid with search and filter WordPress plugin

Tags: ajax, wordpress, masonry

I am trying to use the Masonry grid with the WordPress plugin Search and Filter Pro using ajax to load the posts upon filtering. I am getting the error:

**Error: “cannot call methods on masonry prior to initialization; attempted to call ‘reloadItems’”**

Both [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/faq.html#call-methods-error) and [Search and Filter](https://www.designsandcode.com/wordpress-plugins/search-filter-pro/faqs/) address this issue.

Masonry recommends using this code:

```
$grid.imagesLoaded( function() {
  // init Masonry
  $grid.masonry({
    // options...
  });
  // Masonry has been initialized, okay to call methods
  $grid.append( $items )
    .masonry( 'appended', $items );
});
```

Search and Filter recommends using this code:

```
//detects when the ajax request has finished and the content has been updated
// - add scripts that apply to your results here
$(document).on("sf:ajaxfinish", ".searchandfilter", function(){
    console.log("ajax complete");
    //so load your lightbox or JS scripts here again
});
```

So, I've incorporated this and my final code is:

```
(function ($) {
    var $container = $('.grid');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        // INITIALIZE MASONRY
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.entry',
            columnWidth: '.entry',
            gutter: 40,
        });
        // MASONRY HAS BEEN INITIALIZED, OKAY TO CALL METHODS
        $(document).on("sf:ajaxfinish", ".searchandfilter", function () {
            $container.masonry('reloadItems');
        });
    });

}(jQuery));
```

but nothing changes. I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

function loadMasonry(){

    //$container will always be a new copy
    var $container = $('.featured-grid-thirds');

    //running images loaded again after page load / ajax event 
    $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        // INITIALIZE MASONRY
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.featured-grid-item',
            columnWidth: '.featured-grid-sizer',
            gutter: '.gutter-sizer',
            percentPosition: true
        });
        // Masonry has been initialized, okay to call methods
        // reload masonry
        $container.masonry('reloadItems');
    });
}

//Call on page load etc...
loadMasonry();

//then also call it after ajax event
$(document).on("sf:ajaxfinish", ".searchandfilter", function () {
    console.log("ajax complete");
    loadMasonry();
});


});
```